# WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install

Tags: wamp

When I install WAMP, that show following alert,

The program can't start because MSVCR.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

gave OK, then installed the wamp. When I start, WAMP logo is always 'yellow' color only. That's not return to 'green'.
What is MSVCR100.dll file?
Where i can download it?
and where i can paste that?

Comment: find better solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install#comment59204725_14557245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing

> Where can I get this dll and what directory should it be in? Should I be installing a newer version of the Visual C++ redistribution pack, like the 2012 pack? Should I also install older versions of the redistribution pack one of the articles on the web suggested to remove all the versions of Visual C++ redistribution packs and reinstall them; I only have 2010 pack installed. Almost all of the articles were related to Windows 7 not Windows 8 is there something I should be doing for window 8 Pro

...

> MSVCR100.dll = Visual C++ 2010 Runtime, not the 2012.
>
> 32Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)
>   http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=8328
>
> 64Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

Source [MSVCR100.dll is missing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52f0bd37-9a08-41b6-bb43-fa01ef3ebc4a/msvcr100dll-is-missing)

---

#### Further reading

- [Missing MSVCR100.DLL or MSVCR110.DLL SOLUTION](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608) at the WampServer forum.